# No Coverage Data for Tests in Current Context

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, mstest

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 SP1. When I run "All Tests in Solution", I get code coverage results to show up just fine. However, when I run a subset of tests using "Tests in Current Context", I only see "Cannot find any coverage data (.coverage or .coveragexml) files. Check test run details for possible errors."

A Google search shows that others do get code coverage results when running a subset of tests. Is there a configuration I'm missing somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured out the reason for this, but it still doesn't make complete sense. If I run the tests in the current context by going to "Test -> Debug -> Tests in Current Context", it doesn't work (code coverage is not generated). However, if I do "Test -> Run -> Tests in Current Context", then it works. So far so good, it kind of makes sense that it would only work when not in Debug mode.

But the strange part is if I use the keyboard shortcut for "Test -> Run -> Tests in Current Context" (Ctrl-R, T), it does not work. So I have to run it from the menu instead of using the keyboard shortcut, otherwise it says no code coverage was generated.